# Why is this JS/jQuery acting on multiple inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

The code works as expected on the input field with name 'phone'. It formats the phone number as the user types into it. However, it is adding an event listener to another input, named 'twofactor' and I can't figure out why the event is firing and formatting the input.

**JS**

```
$('input[name=phone]').keypress(function (e) {

    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    }

    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = $(this).val();

    if (e.which == 49 && curchr == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (curchr == 3 ) {
        $(this).val(curval + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 7) {
        $(this).val(curval + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 12) {
        $(this).attr('maxlength', '12');
    }
});
```

HTML in blade

```
<form v-if="!errors.has('hours') && !has_phone_2fa" class="phone-form" action="#" @submit.prevent="send2FA" @keydown="errors.clear($event.target.name)" onkeypress="return event.keyCode !== 13;">
<p v-show="!ordering && items && items.length !== 0">We take orders exclusively via text. It's quick, easy and allows you to reach us anytime with Q's.</p>
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" v-show="!ordering && items && items.length !== 0" v-model="model.phone" class="input" placeholder="Cell Number">
<span class="error-text" v-if="errors.has('phone')" v-text="errors.get('phone')"></span>
<button v-show="!ordering && items && items.length !== 0" @click="send2FA" type="button">Checkout</button>
</form>

    <form v-if="!errors.has('hours') && has_phone_2fa" action="#" @submit.prevent="onPhoneValidate" @keydown="errors.clear($event.target.name)" onkeypress="return event.keyCode !== 13;">
        <p>Please enter the 6-digit code we just sent you to validate your phone number.</p>
        <input type="tel" id="twofactor" v-model="user_phone_2fa" name="twofactor" placeholder="6-digit Code">
        <span class="error-text" v-if="errors.has('2fa')" v-text="errors.get('2fa')"></span>
        <button @click="onPhoneValidate" type="button">Verify</button>
    </form>
```

As you can see, in the console, it shows the event listener is attached to the 'twofactor' input... but why does this happen?
[image: console window]

Comment: use the 'id' instead of 'input[name=phone]'. `$('#phone')`

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Does not work. Still applies to 'twofactor' for some reason. It does however still work on the #phone input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I figured it out, but not sure as to why this is happening. It has to do with the vue directive. "v-if" causes the error, but "v-show" does not and allows it to work perfectly. If anyone can answer as to why this is happening, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied you code, exactly like you send it and there is no event listener is attached to the 'twofactor' input as you can see here.[image] Maybe the problem is in other scripts or something you didn't put in the question, because using only the code you send, everything is working as expected.

Comment: There are no other scripts effecting the input. It got fixed when I switched the vue directive to v-show.